# r googlesheets package Waiting for authentication in browser

Tags: r, oauth, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, httr

I installed the googlesheets package and

```
code:
gs_auth()
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

The browser pop up in a blank website, it is not go to the google auth page.

Below is my session_info():

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

```
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] googlesheets_0.2.2       Rcpp_0.12.14             ggplot2_2.2.1            
quantmod_0.4-11         
 [5] TTR_0.23-2               xts_0.10-0               zoo_1.8-0                
dplyr_0.7.4             
 [9] data.table_1.10.4-3      bindrcpp_0.2             
alphavantager_0.1.0.9000 devtools_1.13.4         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.2   git2r_0.19.0     plyr_1.8.4       
bindr_0.1       
 [6] tools_3.4.2      digest_0.6.12    jsonlite_1.5     memoise_1.1.0    
tibble_1.3.4    
[11] gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.4      
curl_3.0        
[16] xml2_1.1.1       withr_2.1.0      httr_1.3.1       stringr_1.2.0    
knitr_1.17      
[21] hms_0.4.0        grid_3.4.2       glue_1.2.0       R6_2.2.2         
purrr_0.2.4     
[26] readr_1.1.1      magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     
assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2
[31] httpuv_1.3.5     stringi_1.1.6    openssl_0.9.9    lazyeval_0.2.1   
munsell_0.4.3
```

I have checked my httr package is updated, so I have not idea where the problem is. please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the R help for `gs_auth()`, this function is not typically called directly by end users.  Instead, it is called by other functions in the `googlesheets` package when they need to authenticate with Google.

Instead, if you try to get a list of worksheets from a Google account, it will ask you to authenticate with a Google account. For example:

```
 mySheetList <- gs_ls()
```

...will initiate a login sequence that asks you to cut & paste an authentication URL into your web browser. Subsequent steps generate a token that is pasted back into the R console to authenticate.

Details including screen shots on how to authenticate Google Sheets may be found in the [Working with Google Sheets](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/misc-installingRonChromebook.md#working-with-google-sheets) section of my article *Running R and RStudio on a Chromebook*.

Here is an R console log including `sessionInfo()` illustrating the packages and versions used.

```
> library(googlesheets)
> theSheetList <- gs_ls()
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
> theSheetList
# A tibble: 1 x 10
               sheet_title        author  perm version             updated sheet_key
                     <chr>         <chr> <chr>   <chr>              <dttm>     <chr>
1             PokemonStats    greskilabs    rw     new 2017-07-08 22:40:15 13rGxY7S…
 # ... with 4 more variables: ws_feed <chr>, alternate <chr>, self <chr>, alt_key <chr>
>
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] googlesheets_0.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.13     dplyr_0.7.4      assertthat_0.2.0 cellranger_1.1.0 R6_2.2.2         jsonlite_1.5     magrittr_1.5    
[8] httr_1.3.1       stringi_1.1.5    rlang_0.1.2      curl_3.0        bindrcpp_0.2     xml2_1.1.1       tools_3.4.2     
[15] stringr_1.2.0    glue_1.1.1       purrr_0.2.4      httpuv_1.3.5     yaml_2.1.14      compiler_3.4.2   pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[22] openssl_0.9.7    bindr_0.1        tibble_1.3.4    
>
```

Comment: gs_ls() also pops up the browser but still no auth button

Comment: Hmm... which browser are you using? I just ran through the procedure and was able to authenticate on the Chrome browser.

Comment: Chrome as well, it pops up but it’s blank. I wonder it’s the package issue or its dependencies

Comment: It should bring up a login window for your google account. After selecting the account, it will display a window asking you to authorize tidyverse-googlesheets to access Google drive and view / manage spreadsheets.

Comment: Yes it should be like that but for me, it just shows up the browser without any login sign, a blank site without https

Comment: are you able to login to a Google account outside R?

Comment: Yes log in and out smoothly

Answer (score 0):

It is the chrome browser issue rather than any R packages, I have tested in Firefox and safari in Mac which can successfully connected the google sheets.